# For SEO should there be a web page for every URL path segment?

Tags: seo, url, subdirectory

If I have a domain with the URL `example.com/section-1/abc`, should there also be a dedicated web page for `example.com/section-1` from a SEO point of view?

Assume that there is no bread crumb navigation or any links to this page.

Comment: it is highly depending of the site nature and goals

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily. I have directories on almost every site I build that have empty index pages to prevent people from poking around. Example: 'localhost/mysite/images/'  contains an index.php that will redirect them to 'localhost/mysite/'. It's a silly little thing, but SEO really doesn't need to sort through all of my images. And I certainly wouldn't want to give anyone access to a *member* directory, or one where I store my *databases*.

Answer (score 2):

Google [recommends](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/76329) to “Consider organizing your content so that URLs are constructed logically”. So, for example, having such a URL `example.com/news/astronomy/we-are-not-alone`, for me it would be illogical not to have such pages as `example.com/news/astronomy` or `example.com/news` (personally, I quite often delete some parts of the URL to go to the parent directory). Also, in this case it would be a mistake not to receive some traffic for “News” or “Astronomy News” search queries.

Answer (score 1):

*Users* might expect a given sub-URL-path to resolve to a valid page, but search engines (SEO) have no reason to expect this. Search engines "discover" URLs by crawling, they are not in the habit of "guessing".

Comment: Google is most certainly in the habit of guessing URLs.  It uses the most ridiculous  heuristics including looking for Strings in JavaScript that look like they might be URLs.  I believe Googlebot also tries to crawl parent directories.  I often see it index directory listings even when there are no direct links to the directory itself, only to files within it.

Comment: I can see googlebot in my logs going to pages that it could only have gotten to by guessing